# Time series analysis forecast real scale of vales

Tags: python, time-series

I have time series problem, based on the stationary test, the data need to stationarize, here's the detail

I need to eliminate the stationary from time trend for accurate training and forecasting .. this operation resulted in scaling the real values and the forecasting was in this scale so how can i convert the predicted value to its real scale,  (N.B: i used ARIMA for prediction and the eliminating the stationary as per this)

```
DS_log = np.log(DS["Value"])
expwighted_avg = DS_log.ewm(halflife=1).mean()
DS_log_ewma_diff = DS_log - expwighted_avg
```

then i push this value DS_log_ewma_diff to ARIMA.

Comment: Welcome, this is your first question. May I suggest that you edit your post and start by explaining the problem, followed by everything you have already tried to resolve it and conclude with you expectation. Keep each question focused on a single problem and provide as much information as possible to attract attract a knowledgeable user with your answer.

Comment: any help please

Comment: I gave you several suggestions on how you can improve your question, unless you edit the question and provide more information I doubt that you will get a satisfying result. As it stands there is not enough here to assist you. Please edit the question as instructed.